# Voltage protection level Up of SPD (surge protection device)

Tags: surge-protection, over-voltage-protection, insulation, iec

I was going through the datasheet of the below SPD.

https://www.phoenixcontact.com/en-pc/products/type2-surge-arrester-val-sec-t2-3c-350-fm-2905339

It says, Voltage protection level Up ≤ 1.5 kV

[image]

It also says, overvoltage category 3 in insulation resistance which would mean impulse voltage upto 4kV

[image]

[image]

Shouldn't these two actually be the same? am I missing something here?
I would be very grateful if anyone can help me understand this.

Comment: Please link to the data sheet where you got the final image please.

Comment: @Andyaka the images are from the technical data section under this link.
https://www.phoenixcontact.com/en-pc/products/type2-surge-arrester-val-sec-t2-3c-350-fm-2905339
Please click on <expand all> under product details.

Comment: Bad on Phoenix for not providing data sheets on stuff like this. However, I still didn't see the last picture. I'm about done here because I'm pretty much aligned to wanting a data sheet on stuff (for very good reasons that you may not understand).

Comment: sorry, the last pic is from here. (i just did a google search on overvoltage category 3)
https://eepower.com/technical-articles/overvoltage-categories-in-power-supply-systems/#
i totally understand. would be very grateful if you can still help me out.

Comment: @Andyaka i found the datasheet here!
https://www.phoenixcontact.com/en-us/products/surge-arrester-val-sec-t2-3c-350-fm-2905339?type=pdf

Answer (score 0):

> *would be very grateful if you can still help me out. – Gopal*

The voltage protection level (1.5 kV) is the value that the device limits the voltage to when handling a surge current. It's basically saying that it will clamp the voltage to less than or equal to 1.5 kV if dealing with an 8/20 µs surge of peak current 20,000 amps (\$I_n\$): -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/en-us/products/surge-arrester-val-sec-t2-3c-350-fm-2905339?type=pdf).

The 4 kV insulation resistance is telling you that if the three phase voltages were lifted to 4 kV, the insulation wouldn't be compromised with respect to earth.

Two entirely different things.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Gopal we don't give thanks in comments on this site (it's not a forum) so, you should read how to give thanks --> [what should I do when some answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)